# Connect to WSS without port

Tags: apache, mqtt, wss, mosquitto

I have wss:// connection:
https://barykin-pin-up.ru/mqtt/
- it works good.
But

[image: I cant remove port]

My /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:

```
    pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
    persistence true
    persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
    listener 1884
    allow_anonymous false
    password_file /etc/mosquitto/p.txt
    log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
    listener 9001
    protocol websockets
    certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/barykin-pin-up.ru/cert.pem
    cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/barykin-pin-up.ru/chain.pem
    keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/barykin-pin-up.ru/privkey.pem
```

My config (mqttws31.js)

```
    host = 'barykin-pin-up.ru'; 
    port = 9001;
    topic = '#'; 
    useTLS = true;
    username = "guest";
    password = "guest1234";
    cleansession = true;
```

I tried *listener 443* but 
wss://barykin-pin-up.ru:433/mqtt
not worked, and
wss://barykin-pin-up.ru/mqtt
not worked.

I want to make 
wss://barykin-pin-up.ru/mqtt
to work.

What do I start to configure? Apache?

Comment: Update the question with the output of mosquitto when you try and start it with port 433. But I suspect that Apache will already be bound to the port so you will need to configure it to proxy for mosquitto running on a different port